# Cannot create hive connection jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000. spark-submit in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, apache-hudi

I'm running Apache Hudi application on Apache Spark. While I'm submitting an application in client mode its working fine but when I'm submitting an application in cluster mode, getting an error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o196.save.
: org.apache.hudi.hive.HoodieHiveSyncException: Cannot create hive connection jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HoodieHiveClient.createHiveConnection(HoodieHiveClient.java:422)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HoodieHiveClient.<init>(HoodieHiveClient.java:95)
    at org.apache.hudi.hive.HiveSyncTool.<init>(HiveSyncTool.java:66)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.org$apache$hudi$HoodieSparkSqlWriter$$syncHive(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:321)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$$anonfun$metaSync$2.apply(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:363)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$$anonfun$metaSync$2.apply(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:359)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.metaSync(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:359)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.commitAndPerformPostOperations(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:417)
    at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.write(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:205)
    at org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SQLExecution$$executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionMetrics$.withMetrics(QueryExecutionMetrics.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SQLExecution$$withMetrics(SQLExecution.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:93)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After modifying hudi config which "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.jdbcurl" its start working.

Comment: hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.jdbcurl should be given master DNS hostname, when working with EMR and using spark-submit in cluster mode @PradeepSaini

Comment: @VikasChitturi tried to use master DNS hostname - the same issue.

Comment: Ok, can you share the exception from yarn logs? master DNS name should look like this:  jdbc:hive2://ip-XX-XXX-XX-XX.ec2.internal:10000 @dytyniak

Comment: @VikasChitturi An error occurred while calling o107.save.
: org.apache.hudi.hive.HoodieHiveSyncException: Cannot create hive connection jdbc:hive2://ip-172-31-35-94.ec2.internal:10000/

Comment: maybe check your cluster configuration? is it operating in subnet? could be firewall issues? not sure because it worked for me, my EMR has proper security groups enabled for master and worker instances

Comment: @dytyniak please check my configuration in below answer

Comment: @VikasChitturi I am using default config, yes in subnet.

Comment: @dytyniak you don't have to use jdbc, 

'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.use_jdbc':"false",
'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.mode':"hms",

try it with these 2 configs, that way you don't have to pass jbdc url

Answer (score 0):

Following are the hudi write options I am using which worked provided that EMR cluster is configured correctly with proper security groups and subnet settings

```
hudi_write_table_options = {
        "hoodie.table.name": "hudi_data_test",
        "hoodie.datasource.write.table.type": "MERGE_ON_READ",
        "hoodie.datasource.write.storage.type": "MERGE_ON_READ",
        "hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field": ['a','b'],
        "hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field": ['a','b'],
        "hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field": 'c',
        "hoodie.datasource.write.keygenerator.class": "org.apache.hudi.keygen.ComplexKeyGenerator",
        "hoodie.datasource.write.operation": "bulk_insert",
        "hoodie.consistency.check.enabled": "true",
        "hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning": "true",
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable": "true",
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.auto_create_database":"true",
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.database":"hudidatabase",
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table": "hudi_data_test",
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields": ['a','b'],
        'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.jdbcurl':"jdbc:hive2://ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX.ec2.internal:10000/",
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_extractor_class": "org.apache.hudi.hive.MultiPartKeysValueExtractor"
    }
```